# How to freeze first column of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-easyui

I have a table which is implemented by making use of jquery `EasyUI`. I want first column of the table to be freezed and remaing column should have scrollbar when the page is in smaller screen. Code Here [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/0hk1twng/4/)

How can I freeze only `Title1` column.

I tried adding that `Title1` column in `Datagrid-view1` to achieve this. But I couldn't able to find proper solution ..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is here: https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php

According to the documentation, you're looking for the `frozenColumns` option. You take the columns you want frozen out of the `columns` section and add them in `frozenColumns`.

Something like this:

```
frozenColumns: [[
    {field:'f1',title:'title1',width:100,editor:'text'},
]],
columns:[[
    {field:'f2',title:'title2',width:100,editor:'text'},
    {field:'f3',title:'title3',width:100,editor:'text'},
    {field:'f4',title:'NotSave',width:50,
    editor:{type:'checkbox',options:{on:1,off:0}}}
]],
```

You also need to turn off `fitColumns`.

```
fitColumns: false,
```

With these settings I get a horizontal scrollbar in the code you put up.

Comment: +1 here is the fiddle in addtition to the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/0hk1twng/173/